# Why is my window scroll event triggered twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Anyone know why my scroll positions are triggered twice? (the prevScrollPos and the currentScrollPos are posted twice when console logged). I created a custom hook that returns a boolean for true if we're scrolling down and false if we're scrolling up.

update:
The "wheel" event and "touchmove" event fixes this problem so that it logs once but it doesn't create the functionality I want because when I click the button to scroll to the top the navbar still doesn't appear. I put the code for the component that uses this hook below. Since it logs twice, the navbar switches from true/false and appears/disappears often. It fixes itself if you scroll to the end but not back and forth when you are in the middle of scrolling.

```
 import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
    const _ = require("lodash");
    
    // This hook returns a boolean, true: if scrolling down, false: if scrolling up
    export default function useScrollToggle() {
      // Scroll detection and sticky navbar states
      const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = useState(0);
      const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
    
      // wrap callback with debounce so doesn't trigger every scroll
      const onScrollHandler = _.debounce(
        useCallback(() => {
          // current scroll pos
          const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
          console.log(currentScrollPos);
    
          // Boolean reveal navbar on scroll-up (true) or false
          setIsVisible(
            (prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos &&
              // how many pixels needed to scroll up to trigger effect
              prevScrollPos - currentScrollPos > 70) ||
              // ensures that navbar always shows whenever we are at least 10px of top
              // of page
              currentScrollPos < 10
          );
    
          // set state to new scroll position
          setPrevScrollPos(currentScrollPos);
        }, [prevScrollPos]),
        100
      );
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // trigger onScrollHandler when scrolling
        window.addEventListener("wheel", onScrollHandler);
    
        // clean-up
        return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", onScrollHandler);
      }, [prevScrollPos, isVisible, onScrollHandler]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // trigger onScrollHandler when scrolling
        window.addEventListener("touchmove", onScrollHandler);
    
        // clean-up
        return () => window.removeEventListener("touchmove", onScrollHandler);
      }, [prevScrollPos, isVisible, onScrollHandler]);
    
      return { isVisible, setIsVisible };
    }
```

Component that uses this hook:

```
import styles from "./Navbar.module.css";
import NavbarMenu from "./NavbarMenu";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import useScrollToggle from "../../../hooks/useScrollToggle";

export default function Navbar() {
  const router = useRouter();

  // Responsive drop-down menu for mobile
  const [menuToggle, setMenuToggle] = useState(false);

  const menuClickHandler = () => {
    setMenuToggle((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  // True/false scroll toggle custom hook
  const { isVisible: navIsVisible } = useScrollToggle();

  // Brand Title navigate home
  const brandTitleClick = () => {
    router.push("/");
  };

  // ***************************************************************************
  return (
    <nav
      className={`${styles.navbar} ${!navIsVisible && styles.navbarScrolling}`}
    >
      <div onClick={brandTitleClick} className={styles.brandTitle}>
        Brand Title{" "}
      </div>
      <NavbarMenu menuState={menuToggle} onMenuClick={menuClickHandler} />
      <MenuIcon onClick={menuClickHandler} className={styles.navIcon} />
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: What version of react are you using? [react 18 if in strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state) will render effects twice to verify the clean up functions.

Comment: Somehow I can't reproduce your problem in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-rain-dfbe2o?file=/src/App.js     in console.log, I see the scroll event only triggered once.

Comment: I removed strict mode and the error still occurs. I tried using "wheel" and "touchmove" event listeners and it fixes the double logging but it doesn't do the functionality I want to do which is when I click the button to scroll all the way to the top, the navbar re-appears because it doesn't log the window y position when using wheel/touchmove.

Comment: why are you using `useCallback` inside of the callback. hooks need to be registered each time regardless of condition/event

Comment: @DanielA.White I used useCallback because I didn't want the function re-render every time and then a debounce so it doesn't call every pixel of the scroll. I don't think I know what I'm doing if you are asking this so I would love to hear what you think could improve this. Thanks!